# AS2: Access class function from onRollOver

Tags: actionscript, actionscript-2

I am working on a class for building drop down buttons dynamically. Here is excerpt one of my code (located in the Class constructor):

```
_button.onRollOver = function()
            {
                this.gotoAndStop("over");
                TweenLite.to(this.options,0.2 * optionCount,{_y:mask._y, ease:Strong.easeOut, onComplete:detectMouse, onCompleteParams:[button]});
                function detectMouse(button:MovieClip)
                {
                    button.options.onMouseMove = function()
                    {
                        for (var option:String in this._parent.children)
                        {
                            if (this._parent.children[option].hitTest(_root._xmouse, _root._ymouse, true))
                            {
                                if (!this._parent.children[option].active) {
                                    this._parent.children[option].clear();
                                    drawOption(this._parent.children[option], "hover");
                                    this._parent.children[option].active = true;
                                }                               
                            }
                        }
                    };
                }
            };
```

I am attempting to call on the function `drawOption()` which is inside the same class and looks like so:

```
private function drawOption(option:MovieClip, state:String)
    {
        trace("yo");
        switch (state)
        {
            case "hover" :
                var backgroundColour:Number = _shadow;
                var textColour:Number = 0xffffff;
                break;
            default :
                var backgroundColour:Number = _background;
                var textColour:Number = _shadow;
                break;
        }
        option._x = edgePadding;
        option._y = 1 + edgePadding + (optionPadding * (option.index)) + (optionHeight * option.index);
        option.beginFill(backgroundColour,100);
        option.lineStyle(1,_border,100,true);
        option.moveTo(0,0);
        option.lineTo(_optionWidth,0);
        option.lineTo(_optionWidth,optionHeight);
        option.lineTo(0,optionHeight);
        option.endFill();
        var textfield:TextField = option.createTextField("string", option.getNextHighestDepth(), 20, 2, _optionWidth, optionHeight);
        var format:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
        format.bold = true;
        format.size = fontSize;
        format.font = "Arial";
        format.color = textColour;
        textfield.text = option.string;
        textfield.setTextFormat(format);
    }
```

But because I am trying to call from inside an `onRollOver` it seems that it is unable to recognise the Class methods. How would I go about accessing the function without making a duplicate of it (very messy, do not want!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AS2 I prefer to use the `Delegate` class to add functions to event handlers whilst maintaining control over the scope.

You implement it like this:

```
import mx.utils.Delegate;

//create method allows you to set the active scope, and a handler function
_button.onRollOver = Delegate.create(this,rollOverHandler);

function rollOverHander() {
    // since the scope has shifted you need to use 
    // the instance name of the button
    _button.gotoAndStop("over");
    TweenLite.to(_button.options,0.2 * optionCount,{_y:mask._y, ease:Strong.easeOut, onComplete:detectMouse, onCompleteParams:[button]});
}
```

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly how I wanted my syntax in the first place, horrible to have functions within `onRollOver` and local variables. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

everything in the onrollover relates to the button which is rolled over, to access the outer functions, you would have to navigate to the outer class before calling the function in exactly the same way that you are accessing the outer variables, eg:

if the parent of the button contains the function:

this._parent.drawOption(....)

ContainerMC class:

```
class ContainerMC extends MovieClip{

    function ContainerMC() {
        // constructor code
        trace("Container => Constructor Called");
    }

    function Init(){
        trace("Container => Init Called");
        this["button_mc"].onRollOver = function(){
            trace(this._parent.SayHello());
        }
    }

    function SayHello():String{
        trace("Container => SayHello Called");
        return "Hellooooo World";
    }
}
```

I then have a movieclip in the library with the Class ContainerMC and the identitfier Container_mc, which is added to the stage by this line in the main timeline:

```
var Container = attachMovie("Container_mc","Container_mc",_root.getNextHighestDepth());
Container.Init();
```

Edit: added working sample

Comment: `this._parent` finds the `displayObject` that `this` is a Child of not the class it is referenced in. A Class is not a object on the Stage and cannot be accessed through this manner.

Comment: In this case I would normally have my class extend a movieclip as a container for my button + other elements, so that I can access the class methods from events

Comment: My class is extending `MovieClip`, I am not sure what you mean as extending is just a form of inheriting from another class, not scoping your Class. Can you write an example of what you mean?

Comment: creating a sample for quickly

Comment: I see you are exporting a movieclip to actionscript and extending upon that. Makes sense now. This would work but I prefer the delegate option. +1 and thanks for your help :)